# How can I check if a ContentResolver is busy

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I have a button and when user clicks this button, it should update status of the data with the specified id

```
public void updateByClick(int id) {
    myCursor.moveToPosition(id);
    if (myCursor.getShort(myCursor.getColumnIndex(MyTable.STATUS)) == 0) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MyTable.STATUS, true);

        getContext().getContentResolver().update(MyTable.CONTENT_URI, cv,
                  MyTable._ID + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id + 1)});

    }
}
```

The problem is, that if user clicks button fast (so there are a lot of updateByClick events) then update operation calls many times (update isnt happened yet, so status still == 0)

How can I check if ContentResolver (or something else) is busy (currently updating) then I can prevent multiple update calls

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with timeStamps. Every time your update method is called you create a timeStamp with `System.currentTimemillis()` and check the difference with the last saved timeStamp. If it doesn't reach a threshold you don't call the update request.

Comment: I think there are a lot of ways to solve my problem, using time limitations, flags, listeners... But I want to know if there is any method in android system that can help me without such hacks. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to simply ignore button presses that come in to quickly:

```
long prevTouchTime = 0;
long touchTimeout = 1000;
public void updateByClick(int id) {
   long touchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   if (touchTime - prevTouchTime < touchTimeout)
        return;
   prevTouchTime = touchTime;
   //Do everything else
}
```

Comment: Please see comment that I wrote for @dmaxi. Thank you